# how do I get the data I send to server side using ajax $.post?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I use `$.post` to send form data as an array made up of object literals to a `process.php`as follows

```
$('#form').submit(function(e){
        var my_result = JSON.stringify(array);// array is the array where I   store my object literals. It contains only object literals
        alert(my_result);
        $.post('process.php', my_result, function(answer) {
            alert('success'); 
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert('failure');
        });

    });
```

. The data is sent but I do not know how to access the data from the server side and unpack it for storage in a database. Please does anybody have an idea of how to do this? I read previous post but they did not help me at all instead I got more confused.

Comment: Beware, submiting a form cause a redirect/refresh of current web page depending form action attribute. This result in the ajax request being aborted client side and it could cause the server to not handle the request. Firstly, you should prevent this behaviour if you want to be sure your request has enough time to complete. So use `e.preventDefault()`. Then to handle POST variable server side, there is already thousand of thousand available tutos on the net.

Comment: The data parameter for [`$.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) can't be a JSON string, it needs to be a query string or object.

Comment: I removed e.preventDefault() because the same button has to get the data sent and store in a database but when I use e.preventDefault() the php script is not executed so I did not know what else to do.

Comment: i was not aware of that  @4castle. The problem is that if what I send is not JSON how do I access it server side?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the data [using the $_POST global:](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php)

```
$server_side_my_result_var = $_POST['my_result'];
```

Comment: This is what I get " Notice: Undefined index: my_result in C:\wampp\process.php on line 11"

Comment: Can you log what $_POST give to you?

Comment: Also, A. Wolff is right in his comment about preventDefault(). Are you sure you're calling the php script asynchronously and using the POST method? If you skip the preventDefault() call, could be that you're actually calling your form synchronously through a simple GET request. When you click the submit button, does the browser page reload?

Comment: when I click submit the "process.php" is displayed and then the `print_r($_POST)` is executed with this result ` Array ( [submit] => submit )`

Comment: The data I sent is nowhere to be found

Comment: Then is the form itself which is being sent, no AJAX at all I'm afraid. You should check if the ajax request is being made. Keep in mind that, with your actual code, your code intents to submitting a form AND sending a post ajax request. That is surely unintended, you should call event.preventDefault() and make it work that way.